# Whats happening to AWS SQS messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am new to AWS SQS service, to understand the behaviour of SQS trigger of lambda function. I have written a simple usecase with two lambda functions. I have used Standard SQS for this as the order of messages are not important.

**Lambda 1 (logic):**
    writes 1 to 50 in SQS queue as 50 different messages.

**Lambda 2 (trigger lambda for the SQS queue):** *(batch size 10, **concurreny undefied**)*
    Prints the number received from the queue. (Able to see it in cloudwatch logs)

```py
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print (event)
    print("*")
    print(json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])['search_query'])
    time.sleep(5)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

**Scenario 1:**
When i write just 5-10 messages to queue, all the messages are received and are processed in lambda (verified in cloudwatch logs).

**Scenario 2:**
When i write 50 messages to the queue:
    In queue monitoring, it shows all the messages are received. (no messages in available or inflight status). Whereas when i go and check the cloudwatch logs, only 14 lambda instances are invoked which processed 14 messages and printed the details in cloudwatch logs.

**NOTE:** To double verify, i have made changes to Lambda 2 to write the message to DynamoDB, which also has only 14 message details.

Can anyone has an idea what happening to these messages.

**Edit 1:** When concurrency is made to 1, all the 50 messages are processed by lambda function.

**Edit 2:** Thanks for your suggestions, we found the issue it is the way in which we were reading the messages.
json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])

Our assumption was irrespective of batch size SQS will send only one message to lambda.

After doing a couple of tests, we figured out when the lambda function just prints the message (meaning there's no delay in execution), we see SQS is only passing one message at a time even when the batch size is set to 10. However, when there is a delay (time.sleep(5)), then we see SQS passing one message, 2 messages, 7 messages for some lambda invocations. How does SQS Batch size work exactly when integrated with Lambda.
(Added Lambda2 code for reference)

Comment: Do the 14 lambdas only receive one each, or do they each receive a batch of > 1 message?

Comment: @mattfreake from the cloudwatch logs i can say that only one message is received by each lambda. I also made the batch size to 1 and tested it, the behavior is same. Only some messages are getting processed.  If you want me to test any scenario, i will be happy to test it and share you the results.

Comment: 14 lambda "instances" being invoked is normal based on how [SQS-Lambda scaling works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-scaling). Did you open up each CW log stream to check if multiple events were bunched under a single one? For the DynamoDB test, was the batch size set as 1?

Comment: It would probably be easiest if you shared a minimal version of lambda 2, which reproduces the problem and shows how you check that only a single message is received by the lambda (easiest with the logging, rather than the DynamoDB I guess)

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that Lambda2 is not processing the entire batch, but only a single message.

Can you share your code? Are you looping through the entire list of messages in the `Records` element of your [object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)?

It's strange because you state that when concurrency is set to 1, it works -- but setting lambda concurrency to less than 5 for SQS is definitely not recommended :(. Do you mean concurrency or batch size?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we figured out the issue now. We do have a question w.r.t. sqs behavior which we have included in the question(under edit ). Hope you can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sqs-scaling/), if you set a batch size of 10, but your SQS queue has fewer than 1,000 messages, you're less likely to receive a full batch of 10 messages in your invocations. For more information, see [ReceiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) in the Amazon SQS API Reference.